# How to verify github SSH key

Tags: linux, github, ssh-keys, sha

I want to verify that my SSH key in github matches the local file on my computer.

[image]

The github key seems to be SHA256, encoded in base64, but my local key, encoded with this command doesn't seem to match it.

`$ cat ~/.ssh/github.pub | sha256sum | base64`

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An SSH public key in OpenSSH format contains two or three parts, separated by spaces:

- The algorithm name.
- A base64-encoded SSH public key in protocol format.
- An optional comment.

The fingerprint of an SSH key is the base64-encoded SHA-256 hash of the raw public key (that is, without the base64 encoding).  You can script this, but fortunately, there's an easy way to find it out using `ssh-keygen`:

```
$ ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

You can change the file name for the public key to the appropriate one on your system.  On my system, the output looks like this:

```
256 SHA256:E59Xzh/fsZKkCEL46kTLbPFGXyIodA+ntsQL0JWmq9Y bmc@camp (ED25519)
```

The fingerprint is the second piece.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to test that they match is by authenticating by ssh in the command line.

After setting up your ssh-key, type:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection

Comment: This checks all the keys in the key agent, not just the specified one.

Comment: Will check `~/.ssh/id_rsa` instead of the `~/.ssh/github` as in the question

Answer (score 2):

This one will use only the key supplied in `-i` for auth:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/github -o IdentityAgent=none -T git@github.com
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was searching for. The option "-i"